# how to open a url from a linux server on a windows box

Tags: linux, windows

I am running a windows server on my windows machine and want to be able to open a URL in the the web browser of the windows machine.
I would be grateful if anyone could tell me of this is possible and if so how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access an http resource, you would use:

`"http://<YOUR LINUX IP ADDRESS>/"`